# How to loop over dataframe and remove rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to loop over a dataframe and remove rows where the value in the 'player_fifa_api_id' column is equal to the value in the previous row. For some reason, my code isnt working:

```
for i in range(0,len(test)-1):
    print("{} lines out of {} processed".format(i,len(test)))
    if test['player_fifa_api_id'].iloc[i+1] == test['player_fifa_api_id'].iloc[i]:       
        test.drop(test.index[i])
```

Does anyone know where im going wrong? 
Here's a screenshot of the format of the dataframe[image]

Comment: `dataframe.drop` doesn't work `inplace` by default. So set `inplace=True`. But why do you need a for loop for this do, `df.loc[ condition , :]`.

Comment: With pandas you you shouldn't use loops,use `test[test['player_fifa_api_id'] != test['player_fifa_api_id'].shift()]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid looping through a dataframe. There is often much faster and more elegant solutions using vectorized functions. In your case, filter for the rows you want:

```
player_id = test['player_fifa_api_id']

# if the current row is not equal to the previous row, then keep the current row
keep = player_id != player_id.shift() 

# filter for the rows you want to keep
result = test[keep]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why no to use drop_duplicates instead:

```
import pandas as pd

test.drop_duplicates(subset='player_fifa_api_id', keep='first', inplace=True)
```